# How do I sign an Android application as a system app to use DEVICE_POWER permission

Tags: android

Was reading over [Android system application DEVICE_POWER permission error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507776/android-system-application-device-power-permission-error) and [How to sign Android app with system signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature)

I am still unable to sign my application as a system app.  I don't know where /build/target/product/security is.

Do I pull the key off my own device to use for signing my app.

I just want my app to be able to call:

```
private void screenOff(){
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

    long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 1000;
    pm.goToSleep(time);
}
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only sign your application as a system app if you are building Android from source for your project. If you're interested in a hack that will only work on your phone see:

[How to sign Android app with system signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.

Only the device manufacturer can sign apps with the system key - the same way only you can sign apps with your key. And each device (at least each manufacturer) has a different system key. None of them will ever give you that key.

The only way to get to that permission is by building your own device firmware (e.g. [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) so you know that key (`/build/target/product/security` is part of those sources). But if you do that you still can't distribute your app since only you (+ other people using your firmware) have the right key.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info...  My power button is malfunctioning so I was trying to write a quick app to turn the screen off instead of having to wait for a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I think your need is to have your app to have the permission for DEVICE_POWER. yes , the normal apps cannot have that permission.
But you can make your app a privileged one. If you make it a privileged one, in the build, the app will be created in your /system/priv-apps/

to make your app a privileged one, in the Android.mk file , add the below code:
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true

Cheers!!!