# How to send Android device to sleep or programmatically press the power button with Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

How to send Android device to sleep or programmatically press the power button(KEYCODE_POWER) with Kotlin?
Is it possible?
Some example?

Thank you advance!

Answer (score 1):

> In Android (regardless of whether you use Kotlin, Java, whatever) for
>   security reasons it is not possible for an app to make the device
>   sleep, unless your app is a system app provided by the phone
>   manufacturer.

[discuss.kotlinlang.org](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-send-android-device-to-sleep-or-programmatically-press-the-power-button-with-kotlin/13362)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you still can.  Rather old post here https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1210421 says to use gotosleep function.  There are discussions of problems with it for Java -  see below links,  but maybe for Kotlin it will work.

[Attempting to put Android device to sleep, but the PowerManager does not contain a "goToSleep(long) method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459287/attempting-to-put-android-device-to-sleep-but-the-powermanager-does-not-contain?r=SearchResults)

[Android system application DEVICE_POWER permission error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507776/android-system-application-device-power-permission-error?r=SearchResults)

[Android What permissions required to call PowerManager.goToSleep(n) put device in sleep mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710971/android-what-permissions-required-to-call-powermanager-gotosleepn-put-device-i)

Comment: maybe, but from links you provided looks that option is possible for API<21, that is for devices running Android 4 and below.